# What tag should use title of a news?

Tags: html, wordpress

I use WordPress to publish news. What tags should I use for the title? `h1` or `h2`? What tag should I use within the main page, and what tag should I use on the news' page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<h1>` tags should be used to mark up the page's **most important headline**.

Is the title of the news article the most important? Depends.

- If the page is **about** the news article, its headline **is probably the most important**.
- If you're on a page **listing** news articles, it's probably ***not* the most important**.

In that case, on the main page, where you list these articles, you should probably use a `<h2>`, or `<h3>`. On the single article page, it should be the top header.

And no, I don't think the site's logo/slogan should have the `<h1>` tag on every page. Maybe on the home page only. It's definitely not the most important headline on **every** page. I mean, when you come and read an article, you read the dang article, not look at the site's logo.

Answer (score 1):

Madara's advice is good. Use h1 for your headlines on individual posts. Use two or three h2 tags in the body of the text for important sections.

But don't forget the importance of the URL, you need keywords in there as well.

On a news page that lists all news items, make your h1 something like, "Keyword News."

Thus, a site about Libertarian politics, that would mean your h1 on the news list page is "Libertarian News from sitename.tld" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for a little offtopic, but you may be interested in that article:

[Consistent formatting of headings (at blog.editage.com)](http://blog.editage.com/consistent-formatting-of-headings)

Its about paper publications, but knowledge about typography is very important in professional webdesign.

About header levels i have nothing to add, Madara Uchiha wrote everything.